# aggregate query in SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access

I need to do an aggregation of data as follows. This pertains to imports of various grades of ore along various dates. I have the following sample data and want to get cumulative data as on date per grade

```
Grade        Dat               Amount
----------------
A         12/1/2014       100
A         12/4/2014        40
A         12/30/2014       25
A         1/6/2015        100
B         12/24/2014       20
B         12/28/2014        1
B         1/1/2015         30
B         1/2/2015         50
C         12/12/2014       20
C         12/31/2014       15
```

I was looking to get the following

```
Grade        Dat               Amount
----------------
A         12/1/2014       100
A         12/4/2014       140
A         12/30/2014      165
A         1/6/2015        265
B         12/24/2014       20
B         12/28/2014       21
B         1/1/2015         51
B         1/2/2015         101
C         12/12/2014       20
C         12/31/2014       35
```

I tried this

```
select a.grade, a.dat,sum(a.amount) 
from table1 a, table1 b 
where (a.grade=b.grade) and (a.dat>=b.dat) 
group by a.grade, a.dat
```

This messes up- it presents the first row in each grade right, but then doubles the second instance, triples the third etc instead of doing a cumulative aggregation.

I get this

```
project dat Expr1002
A   12/1/2014   100
A   12/4/2014   80
A   12/30/2014  75
A   1/6/2015    400
B   12/24/2014  20
B   12/28/2014  2
B   1/1/2015    90
B   1/8/2015    200
C   12/12/2014  20
C   12/31/2014  30
```

I suspect I am missing something simple

Comment: Can you paste the sample output you need?

Comment: Please edit the question to show desired and actual query results.

Comment: Are you looking for the latest amount per grade? It helps if you add in your question what do you want to see.

Comment: found the comment `want to get cumulative data as on date per grade` but I still don't understand it. Do you want to have a sum of grades? or you want to see the cumulative over time?

Comment: I shared the details- does it help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the following is what you want:

```
select a.grade, a.dat, (select sum(amount) from table1 b
                        where (a.grade=b.grade) and (a.dat >= b.dat))
from table1 a
```

(Assuming there are no duplicate grade/dat rows.)

Answer (score 1):

I will guess that you want to see a cumulative over time thus:

```
select grade
      ,dat
      ,amount
      ,sum(amount) 
           over (partition by grade order by dat range between UNBOUNDED PRECEDING and current row) cumulative_amount
from table1;
```

That gives me the sum of grades until the day of row in the column cumulative_amount.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of SQL are you using? If you are using SQL Server 2012 or above you can use the SUM OVER function. You'll need something like

```
SELECT Grade, 
       Date, 
       SUM(Amount) OVER (PARTITION BY Grade ORDER BY Date ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS CumulativeSum
FROM YourTable
```

Otherwise, try using the CROSS APPLY function.

Comment: was using MS Access 2010